Периодичность обновления виджета android
Возникла задача сделать виджет, который будет по крайней мере раз в минуту получать данные с сервера и выводить их в виджет. Проблема заключается в том, что в документации написано, что обновление виджета может происходить не чаще, чем одного раза в 30 минут (свойство updatePeriodMillis). Нашел как сделать через AlarmManager, но опять же не советуют частое обновление из за того, что будет быстро расходоваться батарея, поэтому возникает вопрос: как тогда работают такие виджеты, как погода или часы? Ведь им нужно более частое обновление, чем один раз в 30 минут

Ни погода ни часы не обновляются каждую минуту. Даже полчаса это много для них. Погода та вообще от 3 до 10 часов по дефолту (во всяком случае в тех что я видел). А что до поддержки связи не знаю как конкретно это реализуется в андоролиде, но в вебе для этого есть сокеты.

вопрос какой? Как обойти тех. лимит? Никак.  Для погоды 30 мин. это более чем достаточно. Так что не темните.

Обновление виджета возможно со скоростью примерно раз в две секунды. Посмотрите ответ по этой ссылке: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1580698/352302
